# Remove multiple white space between text

Tags: javascript

```js
var s = "Hello! I'm  billy! what's    up?";
var result = s.split(" ").join();
console.log(result);
```

Got this result

```
Hello!,I'm,,billy!,what's,,,,up?
```

How can i get rid of this annoying extra spaces between string? So it might look like this.

```
Hello!,I'm,billy!,what's,up?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to find all the spaces throughout the string and rejoin with a single space:

```js
var s = "Hello! I'm  billy! what's    up?";
var result = s.split(/\s+/).join(" ");
console.log(result);
```

You can also do this without using `.split()` to return a new array and just use the `String.replace()` method. The regular expression changes just a little in that case:

```js
var s = "Hello! I'm  billy! what's    up?";
var result = s.replace(/ +/g, " ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @RoelDelosReyes You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as the answer.

Comment: if space is at end of string?

Comment: @JayShankarGupta not needed i can do it with just trim() but man it is quite annoying with extra spaces between strings

Comment: @JayShankarGupta What if the space is at the end? The regular expression used finds all extra space no matter where it is.

Answer (score 1):

You want `replace` and `\s+`

> `\s+` Matches multiple white space character, including space, tab,
>   form feed, line feed.
>
> `trim` to remove extra white space at the start and end of the string

```js
var s = "  Hello! I'm  billy! what's    up?  ";
console.log(s.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = "Hello! I'm  billy! what's    up?";
var result = s.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **replace()** method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern `replaced` by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a `RegExp`, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

```js
var str = "Hello! I'm  billy! what's    up?";
str = str.replace(/ +/g, " ");

console.log(str);

var strr = "Hello!        I'm         billy! what's    up?";
strr = strr.replace(/ +/g, " ");

console.log(strr);
```